# Get maximum and minimum from numbers

Tags: c, ansi-c

I need to print maximum and minimum number from numbers.
Problem is that when i set mn and mx to 0 it just wont work because when user write numbers 1 2 3 4 5 minimum is 0 and not 1 and thats the problem.

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x, mx = 0, mn = 0;
    int i = 1, n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("Your number %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &x);
            if (x > mx) {
                mx = x;
            };
            if (x < mn) {
            mn = x;
            };
    };

    printf("minimum is: %d", mn);
    printf("maximum is: %d", mx);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `;` after `for`- and `if`-statements using curly brackets: `};` should be just `}`

Comment: Un-learn `for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)` as soon as you can and use `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` instead. You *will* need this when you are going to work with arrays (which is probably next in your book).

Comment: Thats from our teacher from college :D But in this case is really better to use 1 instead of 0 for better UX.

Comment: I see -- for the prompt. But you can print `i+1` there. Trust me on this: sticking to 1-based starts *will* bite you back. Working around it for the prompt alone is an entirely normal thing to do.

Comment: Agree with @usr2564301 - use what the machine needs internally, adjust that for human prompts and output.

Comment: For `if (x < mn)` to be true the first time, it is like `if (x < 0)`.  It makes more sense to initialize `mn` with a large number.  `int mn = INT_MAX; int mx = INT_MIN;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both to the first value entered. Then use your current code as it is.

(Except for `system("pause");`. C does not need that.)

Comment: Was about to say the same. Your answer could be completed by pointing the fact there's semi-column at closing `}`

Comment: Well i was wondering about that... But i am new into c and i just dont know how to do it. If u can provide example for me i will be very thankfull.

Comment: @JurajJakubov: Add `if (i == 1)` and store minimum and maximum inside this, else update them.

Comment: Thank very much :)

Comment: "C does not need that." It is not C that needs `system("pause");` but the environment. It allows the user to see the program output before the console closes. If the program is run *from* a console it is not necessary.

Comment: @Cid: (thanks for your edit suggestion, but for a pure logic issue such as this I strongly prefer to *explain* it, rather than to write code-to-fit.)

Comment: @usr2564301 no worries, I understand

Comment: It is the corners that tend to challenge code.  Should input be "0"` (no following numbers) or  "1 0"` (One number with the value of 0), this answer's approach reports the same.  As so often the behavior with such corners is often left to the coder.

Answer (score 2):

> to print maximum and minimum number from numbers.

Initialize `mn,mx` to the opposite extremes rather than both to 0.  No need to make for a special case in the loop.  Good code strives to reduce complexity of loops.

This easily and correctly detects the corner case when no minimum/maximum exist (the empty set).

```
#include <limits.h>

// int mx = 0, mn = 0;
int mn = INT_MAX;
int mx = INT_MIN;

...  code as before

if (mn > mx) {
  puts("No input encountered");
} else {
  printf("minimum is: %d\n", mn);
  printf("maximum is: %d\n", mx);
}
```