# Minimum Maximum Mark

Tags: c, max, min

I need to find the maximum and minimum mark from 5 integers which are inputted by the user. The maximum is being printed out, but the minimum is not. Any ideas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int marks = 0, avg = 0, min = 0, max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a mark: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &marks);

        if (marks > max)
        {
            max = marks;
        }
        if (marks < min)
        {
            min = marks;
        }       
    }

    printf("The maximum mark is: %d\n", max);
    printf("The minimum mark is: %d\n", min);
    //printf("The minimum mark is: %d\n", avg);

    getch();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Hint: `min` starts as 0.  Will any input number ever be less than that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get maximum and minimum from numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614201/get-maximum-and-minimum-from-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Set initial value of min to something higher, like 10000. Because none of your input values probably less than 0.
Or even better, use maximum available value for your data type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    int marks = 0, avg = 0, min = INT_MAX, max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a mark: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &marks);

        if (marks > max)
        {
            max = marks;
        }
        if (marks < min)
        {
            min = marks;
        }       
    }

    printf("The maximum mark is: %d\n", max);
    printf("The minimum mark is: %d\n", min);
    //printf("The minimum mark is: %d\n", avg);

    getch();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Setting it to 10000 is better than 0.  But what if someone inputs 10001?

Comment: You should set min and max values to the first one entered. This way, you'd avoid weird initialization values while preserving the true intent of your program

Comment: @EmanueleGiona I agree for an array of values, but when reading input values I think it makes your code look bad.

Comment: @unlut You just replace `marks > max` with `i == 0 || marks > max`, and similarly for `min`.  Not so bad.

Comment: @Bleach101: "Worked" doesn't mean it's correct. Consider what happens if the user enters a number that's too large, or nothing, or their name, or the word "five", or....